# Creating a child theme within a child theme in Magento 2.1.7

Tags: magento2, theme, parent-child-theme

so I'm relatively new to Magento and downloaded a theme (Eren - off themeforest) to build a site off. The theme i wanted to use (eren-4) is already a child theme to eren-1 (the parent theme). I searched around but had trouble finding an answer.

So in short, I was wondering how to build and reference a child theme off an existing child theme in Magento 2.1.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, instead of creating a child theme within a child theme it's more having a parent and a grandparent theme.

So the structure would be like this:

```
Theme A - Grandparent
   |   
Theme B - Parent
   |
Theme C
```

The instructions for creating a theme can be found here - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

I don't have enough time to write the code sorry but those instructions are very helpful.

Comment: Is possible magento 2.0.0 theme support for magento 2.1.7?

Comment: @Rathinam I'm not too sure what you're asking sorry.